# How can I attach a web page to an email?

Tags: email, browser

I need to send a web page as an email attachment using GMail, not as a link to the page, but the entire page saved and attached to the email. I don't see any way to do this with the Android web browser. Is there a way to do this that I've missed, or are there other browsers that can accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dolphin Browswer HD has an option to "Save Page."  I tried it on this page and it saved it as 1606.htm.  I then went into gmail and chose to "add attachment" and used ASTRO file browser to attach it.

Comment: also, fyi, I was going look on your website for your email and email it to you but it appears that programwith.net is down.

Comment: Yep, its down. I really need to do something about that someday. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The [Xscope browser](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sui.m) lets you save webpages but I can only seem to be able to attach pictures to emails from the Gmail app so you might struggle attaching the webpage.

Comment: If you use something like ASTRO file manager and can find the saved file, you should be able to share it with any number of apps.

Comment: I downloaded and tried Xscope, and it only allows me to download images or linked files. I could not find an option to download an entire page.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Downloading the HTML of a webpage without authorization from the owner of the site would probably be breaking terms of use of said site. If this is your website you maintain/own, then you should be fine here.

As for an app that can view source code of webpages try:

- HTML Source Viewer
- Search Marketplace for "html source" and there should be others too.

Not sure if any of them can copy/paste code, but its worth a look.

Comment: Uhh...you download the HTML of a page in order for your browser to render it, so your statement doesn't make any sense. Besides, all of your browsers on the desktop have "Save as..." functionality.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the browser doesn't actually "download" the code in the sense the code is stored locally on your system. But rather it interprets the code as presented to it by the web server. So I think most people would know what I was stating here. And yes all browsers do have save as functionality, but you need to check the copyright and terms of use of the website you are visiting. Just because you can do something of questionable legality doesn't mean it isn't illegal.

Comment: The code is stored locally on your system. That's what is saved in your browser cache.

Comment: "Breaking terms" is so wrongheaded, I don't know where to start. How do you think the web became successful? People viewing source and copying code, that's how. It was designed from the ground up to force sharing of code.